# Accessing existing embbeded fonts in a .swf

Tags: flash, button, fonts, embedding, flash-cs5

i have embedded the simhei simplified Chinese font in a .swf for a font Library. I need to make a list of buttons, that are labeled with all the embedded fonts in the .swf. All the other languages were done in CS4 so there is font registering and everything and the .as for it. I am pretty new to flash, and i am working in CS5 but i don't know how to get a hold of the font i already embedded to turn it into a font button.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you mean by

> i don't know how to get a hold of the font i already embedded to turn it into a font button.

But if you are looking for a list of all available embedded fonts you can use [`Font.enumerateFonts()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/Font.html#enumerateFonts%28%29).

Comment: by get a hold of, i meant that i want to use the embedded fonts in it i have this method:

public function showEmbeddedFonts ():void{
trace("=====================Embedded Fonts===================");
var fonts:Array = Font.enumerateFonts();
fonts.sortOn("fontName", Array.CASEINSENSITIVE);
for(var i:int = 0; i < fonts.length; i++){
trace(fonts[i].fontName + ",  " + fonts[i].fontStyle);
}
}

but it doesn't work for me in Chinese but it works with all the other languages.